# r - dealing with NAs when using lapply to select sublist elements by position

Tags: r, lapply, na

I have a list of vectors, some of which are `NA`. I need to use `lapply` to select the second-to-last element of each vector. The problem is that `NAs` have length 1, so I cannot access their second-to-last element.

```
MyList <- list(a=c("a","b","c"),b=NA,c=c("d","e","f"))
VectorFromList <- unlist(lapply(MyList, function(x) return(x[length(x)-1])))
VectorFromList
  a   c 
"b" "e"
```

As you can see, the resulting vector is shorter than the original input list, which is a problem if I want to append it as a column in a longer dataframe. My expected result is a vector of the same length of the original list:

```
[1] "a" NA  "c"
```

How do I deal with `NAs` when using `lapply` to select subelements within a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always look for at least the first one ... we can use `max` here:

```
unlist(lapply(MyList, function(x) return(x[max(1,length(x)-1)])))
#   a   b   c 
# "b"  NA "e"
```

or alternatively

```
sapply(MyList, function(x) return(x[max(1,length(x)-1)]))
mapply(`[[`, MyList, pmax(1, lengths(MyList)-1))
```